# Capture the content of a inline preview field (VisualForce)

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to update the content of a span tag with the content displayed on the inline editing preview. See below:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion on how dynamically get the content of that field ?

The following is the code I wrote so far:

```
<apex:page standardController="DeliveryStatusMessage__c">
    <apex:pageMessages escape="false"></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit delivery message">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" id="editButton" value="Edit" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!delete}" id="deleteButton" value="Delete" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save" style="display: none;" />
                <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" action="{!cancel}" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" style="display: none;" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!DeliveryStatusMessage__c.Message__c}">
                        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                            hideOnEdit="editButton, deleteButton" 
                            event="ondblclick" 
                            resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"
                        />
                    </apex:outputField>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <span id="inline-editing-preview-content"></span> // Here I would like to place the content of the inline preview content.
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please include the code that you have created. Please see guidelines on how to ask a good question here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, please do visit the [help] and also read [ask]. They are great resources. Welcome to SFSE! @DaveHumm fun fact, you can add that link with `[ask]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways to do this. I personally used this one. Be aware, this wont work with all field types, but should be fine with text input.

The trick with label is necessary, otherwise "PageBlockSectionItem" loses label.

The trick with "body click" makes functionality same if Enter is pressed or when focus on item is lost when user clicks in different place.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.inlineEditCatch :hidden').change(function() {
        $j('body').click();
        document.getElementById("inline-editing-preview-content").textContent = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="textdonor"]')[0].textContent;
    });
});  
</script>

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Edit delivery message">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" id="editButton" value="Edit" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!delete}" id="deleteButton" value="Delete" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save" style="display: none;" />
            <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" action="{!cancel}" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" style="display: none;" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="inlineEditCatch">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.DeliveryStatusMessage__c.fields.Message__c.Label}"></apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!DeliveryStatusMessage__c.Message__c}" id="textdonor">
                        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                                                hideOnEdit="editButton, deleteButton" 
                                                event="ondblclick" 
                                                resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"
                                                />
                    </apex:outputField>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<span id="inline-editing-preview-content"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all such `span` tags with the following vanilla `Javascript`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.inlineEditModified')
```

The `jQuery` equivalent would be:

```
jQuery('.inlineEditModified')
```